# How to get root access to a pod in openshift 4.0

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, openshift

We have an OpenShift v4.0 deployed and running. We are using Open Data Hub pods framework within Openshift wherein we have got our jupyterhub along with spark.

Goal is to read a bunch of csv files with spark and load it into mysql. Error I was getting is mentioned in this tread [How to set up JDBC driver for MySQL in Jupyter notebook for pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63677107/how-to-set-up-jdbc-driver-for-mysql-in-jupyter-notebook-for-pyspark).

One of the solution is to copy the jar file in spark master node. But I am not having access to pod as root user.

How can I get access to root within a pod in Openshift?

Comment: The pod's filesystem will be emphemeral, won't it? That is, even if you can do the copy you need, the pod filesystem will be restored to its standard state if it restarts. This is a problem that needs to be tackled at the deployment stage, doesn't it? Or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 0):

@roar S, your answer is correct, however, it is preferable to create your own SCC identical to the "anyuid" SCC (call it "my-anyuid") and link the new SCC it to the system account.
(and your link points to OCP v3.2 where the question is about OCP v4.x)

We had previous bad experience with this as the upgrade from OCP v4.2 to v4.3 failed because we did what you proposed. In fact "add-scc-to-user" "modify" the target SCC and the upgrade process ddidn't like it

To create a SCC similar to`anyuid`, just extract the anyuid manifest (`oc get scc anyuid -o yaml`)save it, remove all linked SA in the manifest, change the name and create the new one

https://docs.okd.io/latest/authentication/managing-security-context-constraints.html